# Find longest word in a sentence recursively

Tags: java, string, recursion

So I need to find the longest word recursively, I've written the code, but it's not working, and I have no idea what to fix.

```
        public static String longestWord(String sentence)
{
    int i = sentence.indexOf(" ");

    if (i==-1){
        return sentence;
    }

    else{
        String first = sentence.substring(0,i);
        String rest = sentence.substring(i+1);

            if(first.length()>=rest.length()){
                return longestWord(first);
            }
        else{
            return longestWord(rest);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a question. Please find bits you are confused about and rephrase them as questions. Remember that SO is not a site that solves homework problems for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is this a homework question? If so, you should add the homework tag. Did you try using the debugger to step through the code to see what's not working as you'd expect? Posting a bunch of non-working code and saying "please fix whatever is wrong" isn't an appropriate question for this site. Please take a few minutes to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) in order to become more familiar with how to ask questions here, as well as what questions are (and aren't) proper to ask here. Thanks. :)

Comment: Must it be recursive? or is a loop acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
if(first.length() >= rest.length())
```

should read like:

```
String res = longestWord(rest);
if(first.length() >= res.length())
```

Comment: Not necessarily. This is a useful optimization. Clearly if the first word is at least as long as the rest of the string, the rest of the string cannot contain a word which is longer.

Comment: But the else path may discard the longest word in the original version.

Comment: Original version is not correct when first is the longest word, but first.length<rest.length.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not work is that you are ignoring the length of the `longestWord(rest)`: instead of comparing the length of the initial word and the rest of the sentence, you should compare the length of the initial word to the length of the longest word found in the rest of the sentence.

```
String first = sentence.substring(0,i);
String rest = longestWord(sentence.substring(i+1));
return first.length()>=rest.length() ? first : rest;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your basic approach is sane: you're breaking the input into two: the first word, and the rest of the string. But then the logic is bungled a little bit.

If the first word is longer than the entire rest of the string, you should just return `first`, not `longestWord(first)` (although, you do handle that case: `longestWord` will notice that the word cannot be split and just return it. It's pointless though).

Secondly, if that is not the case, you cannot assume that the first word is not the longest word. You must capture the return value of `longestWord(rest)`, and then compare that word's length to the length of `first`. If that word is longer, then return it. Otherwise return  `first`.

The essence of "divide and conquer" by recursion is that you solve some smaller versions of the problem, and then integrate those results. Don't forget this second part. This is not a binary search tree search where the data is organized such that you can just recurse to one half of the space or the other to find the answer. You don't know where the longest word might be.

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach to solve the question:

```
public static String longestWord(String sentence) {
    return longest(sentence.split("\\s+"), 0, 0);
}

private static String longest(String[] words, int idx, int longest) {
    if (idx == words.length)
        return words[longest];
    return longest(words, idx+1,
        words[idx].length() > words[longest].length() ? idx : longest);
}
```

First, in `longestWord()` the sentence gets split by its spaces, producing an array of words. From that point on, the method `longest()` recursively iterates over all the words passing the index of the longest one found so far in the `longest` parameter, until there are no more words. This is an efficient answer, as it doesn't create substrings at each step.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.kota.java;
import java.util.*;

class LongestWord{
    String str = "Ram is intelligent boy";
    String stringArray[] = str.split("\\s");

    public String compare(String st1, String st2) {
        if (st1.length() > st2.length()) {
            return st1;
        } else {
            return st2;
        }
    }

    LongestWord() {
        String word = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                word = stringArray[0];
            }
            word = compare(word, stringArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Longest word = " + word);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LongestWord();
    }
}
/**
 * Out put : Longest word = intelligent
 * 
 * */
```